# Pass a variable from one file to another c#

Tags: c#

I have two .cs files (`Hex2Bin.cs` and `Program.cs`) and I want to pass the variable `end_addr` from `Program.cs` to `Hex2Bin.cs`

My code in Program.cs:

```
class Program
{
    enum to_exit {
        exit_ok = 0,
        exit_invalid_args,
        exit_to_few_args,
        exit_invalid_input_file,
        exit_invalid_args_file,
        exit_permission_denied,
        exit_unexpected_eof
    };

    // class value holders
    static String args_file_name = "";
    static String in_u1_name = "";
    static String in_u22_name = "";
    static String out_name = "";
    static short end_addr = 0x0000;                 // 4-digit Hexadecimal end address
    static Byte[] version_code = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };    // 3 bytes version, 1 for extra info
}
```

Is there anyway I could do this? I know how to do it in c, but I'm very new to c#. Thanks.

Comment: Your code looks like C. In a typical C# application, which is object oriented, you would have Properties or normal class variables, not static variables (why is this stuff static here?). You would instantiate whatever class you've defined in Hex2Bin and set some property on it, then invoke some method that does whatever it does.  This code looks like functional code, not object oriented code. Was there a reason you chose C# for it?

Comment: To be honest, it's someone else's code that I was tasked to modify with hardly any experience with c#!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you declare the variable like this:

```
public static short end_addr = 0x0000;
```

then from another class you can use it like this:

```
Program.end_addr
```

but don't do this, is not object oriented!

if your class Hex2Bin is used/invoked by the Main method of Program class, you should be able to pass your variables as input parameters of the methods you call or set them as properties of the classes/objects you use...

Comment: Thank you that was very simple! I just made end_addr a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't work like C with respect to `static` variables. You can make the variable `end_addr` available outside the `Program` class by making it a `public` field. By default, fields are `private`.

```
public static end_addr = 0x0000;
```

And then it can be accessed like so:

```
var x = Program.end_addr;
```

However, I would recommend that you spend a little more time familiarizing yourself with C# idioms and conventions. It seems like your still thinking about C# in terms of C, and they are very different.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to mark `end_addr` as `public` like so

```
public static short end_addr = 0x0000;
```

Then you can access it from anywhere like this

```
Program.end_addr
```

It's a better practice though to use [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) rather than fields for exposing data.

```
// Property
public static short end_addr { get; private set; }

// Constructor
public Program()
{
    // Initialize property value.
    end_addr = 0x0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your background in C, I think you may be mixing runtime with compile time issues.

However, in Hex2Bin.cs, you can create a static method that updates a static variable.

```
class Hex2Bin 
{
    static short end_addr = 0x0000;
    static void updateEndAddr(short endAddr)
    {
        end_addr = endAddr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about 'files' but what you really want to do is to pass data from your program's entry point (`Program.cs`) to a an object of a class (or method of static class) that will process the data, am I right?

If so, this should be pretty simple. You either have to modify your Program.cs and create an instance of the class (the one from Hex2Bin.cs) like this

```
...
Hex2Bin hex2bin = new Hex2Bin( end_addr );
...
```

I assume that the Hex2Bin is as follows:

```
public class Hex2Bin
{
    private short endAddress;
    public Hex2Bin( short endAddress )
    {
        this.endAddress = endAddress;
    }
}
```

this will allow you to use the value of `end_addr` from `Program.cs`

Another approach is to pass it directly to the method that will make use of it:

```
Hex2Bin.Method(end_addr);
```

and in the Hex2Bin file:

```
public static void Method(short endAddress)
{
    //... do the work here
}
```